# Sql Server Cursor infinite loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

```
DECLARE @UnitPrice DECIMAL(5, 2);
DECLARE @ProductId INT;
DECLARE UnitPriceUpdateCursor CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT ProductID
    FROM Products;
OPEN UnitPriceUpdateCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM UnitPriceUpdateCursor INTO @ProductId;
WHILE(@@Fetch_Status = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @UnitPrice = UnitPrice
        FROM Products;
        IF(@UnitPrice BETWEEN 5 AND 10)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Products
                  SET
                      UnitPrice = 15.00
                WHERE ProductID = @ProductId;
        END;
            ELSE
        IF(@UnitPrice BETWEEN 15 AND 20)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Products
                  SET
                      UnitPrice = 25
                WHERE ProductID = @ProductId;
        END;
        FETCH NEXT FROM UnitPriceUpdateCursor INTO @ProductId;
    END;
CLOSE UnitPriceUpdateCursor;
DEALLOCATE UnitPriceUpdateCursor;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Comment: You have no FETCH NEXT inside the loop so @@Fetch_Status never updates.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here in the first place? This is a simple update statement.

Comment: I assume you meant to set @ProductId in your cursor. As posted this would do nothing because the value would be NULL and no row would ever get updated.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your entire cursor logic with a single update statement. This should do the same thing.

```
Update Products 
set UnitPrice = case when UnitPrice = 18.00 then 20 
                    when UnitPrice < 25.00 then 30
                    else UnitPrice
                    end
```

--EDIT--
The question was changed after I posted my original answer. This should accommodate the new logic you want.

```
Update Products 
set UnitPrice = case when UnitPrice > 5 and UnitPrice < 10 then 15.00 
                    when UnitPrice > 15 and UnitPrice < 20 then 25
                    else UnitPrice
                    end
```

Comment: thank . its working but i want range opertor multiple case i.e between

Comment: Begin Update Products set UnitPrice = case when UnitPrice between 5 And 10 then 15
                     when UnitPrice  between 11 AND 15  then 20
         else UnitPrice
                    end

Comment: Well...you changed the logic in your question after I posted my answer. See the updated answer, it contain your new rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following statement

```
Declare @UnitPrice decimal
Declare @ProductId int
Declare UnitPriceUpdateCursore  Cursor FOR
    Select UnitPrice From Products 
OPEN  UnitPriceUpdateCursore
Fetch Next From UnitPriceUpdateCursore into @UnitPrice
While (@@Fetch_Status=0)
Begin
    select @UnitPrice=UnitPrice from Products where @ProductId=ProductId

    IF(@UnitPrice =18.00)
    Begin 
        Update Products set UnitPrice=20 where ProductId=@ProductId
    End
    ELSE IF(@UnitPrice <25.00)
    Begin
        Update Products Set UnitPrice=30 Where ProductId=@ProductId
    End
    Fetch Next From UnitPriceUpdateCursore into @UnitPrice
End
Close UnitPriceUpdateCursore
Deallocate UnitPriceUpdateCursore
```